# Instaliing J2EE on Android Developers Tool (ADT Bundled Eclipse from Android)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I am trying to install J2EE Plugin in Android Bundled Eclipse(Downloaded from Android Developers Site). 
Steps That I performed :

1) http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates link added in Install New Software

2) Selected the Web Tools Platforms 3.1.1

3) Clicked Next.

4) Deselected on Eclipse XML (already installed Package)

5) Clicked Next.

And finally got this error.

I am getting this error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Dali Java Persistence Tools 
  2.2.1.v200908270220-7L7OALFBBoPR9QdeWV1je (org.eclipse.jpt.feature.feature.group    
  2.2.1.v200908270220-7L7OALFBBoPR9QdeWV1je) 
  Missing requirement: Dali Java Persistence Tools - DB UI 1.1.100.v200906070220 
  (org.eclipse.jpt.db.ui 1.1.100.v200906070220) requires 'bundle 
  org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui [1.1.0,1.2.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Dali Java Persistence Tools 2.2.1.v200908270220-7L7OALFBBoPR9QdeWV1je 
  (org.eclipse.jpt.feature.feature.group 2.2.1.v200908270220-7L7OALFBBoPR9QdeWV1je)
   To: org.eclipse.jpt.db.ui [1.1.100.v200906070220]
```

Please suggest me how to install J2EE plugin in Android ADT. Please suggest me if I can Install any plugin or is there any other URL for ADT Eclipse to install plugins.

Comment: Where did you come across that old update site URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions at http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F .  It looks like the bundle corresponds to Eclipse 4.2.2, Kepler SR2, meaning you should use http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/ and http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/kepler/ .